# Use a CURSOR to move data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I maintain a list of new contacts that is sent from a subsidiary. Each month a list of contacts is sent to me. The list is complete and I only need the last few dozen rows to be added to the contacts list. I need to maintain the redundant lists for records purposes.

I am trying to use a CURSOR to inspect the monthly inbound tables and place them into master list?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's also helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: "I am trying to use a CURSOR to inspect the monthly inbound tables and place them into master list?" This sentence as a question means you need to seek medical help as you are ASKING US TO EXPLAIN TO YOU WHAT YOU DID (and that without code).

Comment: If you are only ever adding to the master list where is the redundancy?. If there are records that have to be updated as well as added then that would be significantly different question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't required and should not be using CURSOR to do that.

Basically just use NOT EXISTS to check for existing and insert

```
INSERT INTO master_list (contact_id, contact_name, . . . )
SELECT contact_id, contact_name, . . 
FROM   source_contact_list s
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
             SELECT *
             FROM   master_list x
             WHERE  x.contact_id = s.contact_id
       )
```